# is web view wrapper app get rejected by apple app store?

Tags: ios7

I am creating the app which loads the HTML page in UIWebView. Here, we are doing the offline capture feature for the app(doing encryption and storing data to the device using coredata).

Note : My App UI is completely UIWebView.

Recently, I heard that these kind of apps gets rejected by apple app store.

If it is true or some one have the same rejection, please provide the info.

your help could be appreciated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because App Store support staff can provide an official answer.

Comment: [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just using HTML as an implementation method of your UI doesn't become a reason for rejection. This once has been an issue a few years ago, and Apple formally does not limit implementation method anymore. If they do, most of hybrid app platforms couldn't work.

If someone have rejection of their HTML UI app, that should be due to bug or crude implementation of the app features rather than using of HTML stuff. In many cases HTML based UI on mobile systems fails to provide nice responses, then you need to care a lot not to break them. If the reviewer think your app is broken, then your app will be rejected.

Take care that the basis of *normal or working* state is always Apple's native app.

Comment: Thanks Eonil for the response.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. An app which its purpose is only to preview a website will be rejected based on Apple's Review Guidelines. Your app has to offer a minimum functionality and introduce at least some App Specific values to be acceptable. You can refer to this link for more information on Apples policy for releasing new applications:
[App Store Review Guidelines Minimum Functionality](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#minimum-functionality)